# Convert BIGINT result from MySQL COUNT() to INT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can this be done in 1 statement and retrieved by PHP?

```
SELECT COUNT(Date) AS RowCount FROM `Health_Data` WHERE Weight < 200; 
SELECT (INT) RowCount;
```

Apparently at least some versions of PHP can't handle the BIGINT type, so I want to convert it to an INT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that PHP can't support a BIGINT, but that you're running a 32-bit PHP version that can't support numbers as large as you're trying to accommodate.

The best option would be to upgrade to a 64-bit version, because how are you even running 32bit at this point in time?

The less-good, if you're *really* stuck, option is to:

1. Cast the number to a string to get it out of mysql and into PHP:

   ```
   SELECT CAST(COUNT(Date) AS CHAR(32)) AS RowCount FROM `Health_Data` WHERE Weight < 200;
   ```
2. Use [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) functions if you need to do math on those numbers in PHP.